# constraintsMap's type (interface java.util.Map) is not supported

Tags: grails, groovy

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: constraintsMap's type (interface java.util.Map) is not supported
14:44:24.456 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
14:44:24.456 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
14:44:24.456 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
14:44:24.456 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
14:44:24.456 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
14:44:24.456 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
14:44:24.457 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
14:44:24.457 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
```

Groovy unit test

```
    void testPromote_happyPath()
    {
        //setup
        //add input params
        controller.params['id'] = ["1", "2", "3"]
        controller.params['sId'] = 37
        controller.params['cId'] = 38

        //invoke
        controller.promote()

        //verify
        verifyPromoteSuccess()
    }
```

Has anyone seen this error before and know how to fix it?  This happened after upgrading grails to 3.1.11 from 2.4.4

Did the constraintMap type change between these versions of grails?

Comment: Which method is throwing the exception and what is in that method?

Comment: "Did the constraintMap type change between these versions of grails?" - Yes